# Tool to make complicated setup (InstallShield or custom app)

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, installation, windows-installer, installshield

I'm looking into creating a user friendly setup wizard which does the following:

1. Ask the user for a server name.
2. Ask the user for a database name.
3. Ask the user for a Microsoft Nav database name and server
4. Setups database in SQL Server (with info provided in number 3)
5. Runs setup scripts in SQL Server
6. Runs setup of server app (which I have made)
7. Runs setup of client app
8. Asks the user for some data (defaults which will be written into tables in SQL Server)
9. Imports some data into SQL Server
10. Runs a custom Microsoft Nav setup of external component
11. Other requirements (I might want to edit text files (like web.config in .NET based on user input etc.)

I'm thinking that creating an wizard in .NET or JRuby would be my best bet because I have looked into InstallShield and it might not contain everything I need.

Any suggestions on how to develop a setup wizard like this?

Johann

Comment: I can think of ways of doing all of this using InstallShield.  There are dozens of requirements and probably hundreds of questions in learning how to us InstallShield to implement those requirements.  Perhaps you should look for an InstallShield consultant to help you with this project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do most of what you require with InstallShield, but not all, and you need to be aware that what you do will be very hard to debug. Writing an installer of this magnitude is a skill-set all of its own, not for the newcomer.

Alternatively you could separate out the functionality - write a simple installer that does the absolute basics, then write a separate configuration utility with which you'll be able to do anything you want.

Comment: InstallShield Basic MSI can do all of this.  You can do custom dialogs and then use the properties in SQL search and Replace statements and XML XPath statements.  Setup/Feature Prereqs can be used to serialize dependency packages and so on.  All very doable if you really understand how to use the tools.

Answer (score 1):

A wizard may sound like a good idea, but when you start working on it you will realize that it's not that simple. Custom installer engines are hard to make. Also, you need to be very familiar with application deployment to cover the basic caveats.

Using an existing setup tool is easier. Most setup authoring tools (both free and commercial) can do what you need. Here is a list which can get you started:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software